# Download files from www directory

Tags: r, download

I have a .zip folder containing 300 .csv files. I would like to download that .zip folder. I tried the following code

```
output$BreastSample <- downloadHandler( 
    filename <- "BreastCancer.zip",
    content <- function(file){
      file.copy("www/BreastCancer(301).zip", file)
    })
  outputOptions(output, "BreastSample", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

But I get the following error

> Error opening file: 2
>   Error reading: 9

Comment: Can this file be found online so that this is reproducible?

Comment: No problem in code. I suggest you to cross check the file name `BreastCancer(301).zip` . May be there is any space.

Comment: @AaghazHussain . Oh my bad. Thanks for pointing out correctly. I had one space before `.zip`. Thanks